# marching query does not exist in if statement

Tags: python, django, get, match

well go to the question. I make this query:

```
Puntuaciones.objects.filter(bar__id=b).get(usuario=v.usuario2)
```

This works perfect, but when i put this in a if statement, like this:

```
if(Puntuaciones.objects.filter(bar__id=b).get(usuario=v.usuario2)):
```

I have a problem, when the query returns a object Puntuaciones i haven't any problems, but when there isn't a result it throws me:

```
Exception Value: Puntuaciones matching query does not exist.
```

So my question is, How i can do a if statement for a query if this query can be  unsuccessful.

I try with Q objects, with exists()(this just works for querysets... I dont know how make it work. Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Where are you making this query? Is it somewhere that get_object_or_404 would work for you? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) is either returning an object or throws `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception, catch it with the help of `try/except`:

```
try:
    Puntuaciones.objects.filter(bar__id=b).get(usuario=v.usuario2)
    # do something if object was found
except Puntuaciones.DoesNotExist:
    # do smth if nothing found
```

Another options is to use [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

```
if Puntuaciones.objects.filter(bar__id=b, usuario=v.usuario2).exists():
   # do something if object was found
```

Comment: I tried the try/except thing before., but i really want not to do anything when the except and with try/except on the except line show me a expected an indented block error.

Comment: @Tzomas sure, cause you should put smth into the `except` block. Put `pass` if you don't want to do anything if an object wasn't found.

Comment: exists() doesnt work, said that Puntuaciones has not object exists(). But the except with pass works. TY!

Comment: @Tzomas ok, great, I've fixed the `exists()` option, give it a try.

Comment: its works too! when i saw the domentation of query give me understand that with that kind of querys i give back bar__id=b or usuario=v.usuario2) . Other think learned! really thx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a try: except: pair. That way, when the exception is triggered, you will be in the appropriate location to perform the code. Note that you really should use the correct exception type in the setup. Note that if you want to skip processing in the except, you need to put in an explicit pass (python noop) statement. Otherwise you will get an indentation error.

```
try:
  if(Puntuaciones.objects.filter(bar__id=b).get(usuario=v.usuario2)):
    # put code in here
    pass # dummy statement to be replaced by actual code.
except:
  # Put exception code here.
  pass
```